# How to create an expanding menu off of clickable points on an imagemap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So I have this body image that I want to use as a kind of navigation point to access rehabilitation exercises for each body part. I've mapped the points on the image so they're clickable, but I then want to make it so when a point is clicked, a dropdown menu appears next to that point with more options. For example, if the shoulder is clicked, the options Weakness, Pain, and Soreness might appear off to the right of that point. I've never used an image map before and I can't find how to make an element appear relative to one of the map points. If I could nest a list inside each point, then I think I could display each menu only when the relevant body part was clicked, but it doesn't look like that's how image maps work. Is there a better way to do this? Here's the codepen I started with, I didn't get very far, but I feel like there must be a better way to accomplish this. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJeLWa

CodePen code since I can't link it without including some code:

```
<div id="frontBody">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMcB.png" alt="frontBody" usemap="#frontBody" id="frontBody">
</div>

<map name="frontBody">
    <area shape="rect" coords="176,106,199,136" alt="Shoulder">
    <area shape="rect" coords="171,270,197,307" alt="Hip">
    <area shape="rect" coords="225,280,254,309" alt="Wrist">
    <area shape="rect" coords="145,428,171,459" alt="Knee">
    <area shape="rect" coords="138,547,163,578" alt="Wrist">  
</map>
```

Comment: Personally, I believe image maps are not used as much anymore in favor of SVG. Basically, image maps are not scalable, and with an SVG, you can easily manipulate or attach events to those elements. A quick search yielded a nice article on the comparison of the two: http://thenewcode.com/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps

Comment: That does look like a good alternative, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to do that at work; getting new software installed is a slow process and I don't think I have anything on this computer right now to manipulate or create an SVG.

Comment: There are plenty of online resources that will help you create SVGs within the browser itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is not very advanced regarding positioning or style but would give you a starting point (done using jQuery library).

```js
var items ={
  Shoulder:[{txt:'Sh #1',link:'http://google.com'},{txt:'Sh #2',link:'http://google.com'}],
  Hip:[{txt:'Hip #1',link:'http://google.com'},{txt:'Hip #2',link:'http://google.com'}],
  Knee:[{txt:'Knee #1',link:'http://google.com'},{txt:'Knee #2',link:'http://google.com'}],
  Wrist:[{txt:'Wrist #1',link:'http://google.com'},{txt:'Wrist #2',link:'http://google.com'}]
}
var $menu = $('#menu').click(function(){
   $(this).hide()
})

$('area').click(function(e) {
  var part = this.alt,   
    $cont = $('#menu-content').empty();
     // position menu based on coordinates of click event
     $menu.show().css({
      top: e.clientY,
      left: e.clientX
    });

  $.each(items[part], function(_, item) {
    $cont.append('<a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.txt + '</a>')
  })
})
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute; background: white;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frontBody">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMcB.png" alt="frontBody" usemap="#frontBody" id="frontBody">
</div>

<map name="frontBody">
  <area shape="rect" coords="176,106,199,136" alt="Shoulder">
  <area shape="rect" coords="171,270,197,307" alt="Hip">
  <area shape="rect" coords="225,280,254,309" alt="Wrist">
  <area shape="rect" coords="145,428,171,459" alt="Knee">
  <area shape="rect" coords="138,547,163,578" alt="Wrist">
</map>

<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-hide">
    Hide[X]<br>
  </div>
  <div id="menu-content">

  </div>
</div>
```

**[JS fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8wjew7fx/1)**

Comment: Thanks, I'm not great with Jquery yet, but this looks pretty functional. I like it.

Comment: Hadn't noticed there wasn't a jQuery tag on question...here's a vanilla js version https://jsfiddle.net/unt7Lkhp/2/

Comment: Oh, that wasn't a problem, but thanks for swapping it to js, easier for me to make sense of. Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help, using some Javascript.

```
<map name="frontBody">
    <area shape="rect" coords="176,106,199,136" alt="Shoulder" onclick='showCoords(event)'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="171,270,197,307" alt="Hip" onclick='showCoords(event)'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="225,280,254,309" alt="Wrist" onclick='showCoords(event)'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="145,428,171,459" alt="Knee" onclick='showCoords(event)'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="138,547,163,578" alt="Wrist" onclick='showCoords(event)'>  
</map> 

<div style='display:none;' id='menu'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Item 1
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in your script file.

```
function drawBox(x,y){
  document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('menu').style.position = 'absolute';
  document.getElementById('menu').style.top = y+'px';
  document.getElementById('menu').style.left = x+'px';
}
function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    drawBox(x,y);
}
```

I didn't style it for you, because I didn't know what you wanted.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xop1gwe/)

Of course if you want to use jQuery, that makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but the fiddle doesn't do anything atm. Looking at your code though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the save, it works now. JSFiddle has a bug where the JS doesn't always load unless you use <script> tags

Comment: Yep, working now haha. Looks great, I'll use something like this.